# WannaCrypt - Localized XP Patch installation fails

Tags: windows, windows-xp, wannacrypt

In my company we have a couple of Windows XP machines around for running legacy software. One of them is in Windows XP SP3 English and the other in Windows XP SP3 Greek (don't ask, I just found them this way when I came to the company).

My issue is with WannCrypt XP patch, while I can install it normally in the pc with the english version, it is impossible for me to do it in the one with the localized one.

I tried downloading the localized versions of the patch from the blog post Microsoft wrote about the WannaCrypt attack and from the Update Catalogue. It alway states that my computer has different language then the one in the update.

I found some posts regarding this from other languages as well in a couple of forums, with no solution whatsoever.

Any info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had to deal with a Windows XP SP3 (Spanish) x86.

I had your same problem when downloading from the link in the blog post you mention: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msrc/2017/05/12/customer-guidance-for-wannacrypt-attacks/

But it worked when using the Update Catalog: http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4012598

Make sure you use the right architecture version (x86 vs x64).

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DonaldDuck - While I normally would agree, In this case, there isn't anything to quote except (the links contained within the article to the Windows XP patch) which the author claims doesn't work.  There also isn't anything to quote from the catalog website for obvious reasons.  I have changed the catalog website link to point to the relevant listing for KB4012598 though.

Comment: [KB4012598 - Windows XP SP3](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/csa/csa/secu/2017/02/windowsxp-kb4012598-x86-custom-enu_eceb7d5023bbb23c0dc633e46b9c2f14fa6ee9dd.exe)

Comment: I am accepting this, though I had already done it. I am pretty sure I did the Update Catalog step correctly, but the file was the same name with the one in the blog post. When I just tried it now, it gave me a different file and it worked. Thnx!